# send a GUI update in response for UPDATE and PUT

Tags: rest, http, http-headers, http-verbs

I have a web application: webserver and SPA Front-End. The webserver has a REST API.

Each entry has some stats and updated on every add, update or delete operation. The stats is calculated on the server.

What I want to do is to send an update message in the response body of PUT, POST, DELETE. Front-end will handle it and update accordingly.

What are the drawbacks of this solution? Does it break the REST conventions? Is there a name for such technique?

P.S. I don't think it's a common practice. As an alternative it's possible to push stats changes by using WebSocket.

Comment: What is this update about? Could you please describe the resources you have? What are the URLs?

Answer (score 0):

You say the resources do already include these stats, which are calculated on the server. In this case you can return the actual updated representations on the `PUT`, `POST` and `DELETE` requests. The specification explicitly allows you to return a representation of the resource you just updated.

It does not matter whether the resources have some automatically calculated parts or not, they do not have to be one-to-one mappings of some database entities.

Obviously if you want to notify *all* clients of the change, then either all clients would have to regularly poll some resource, or implement some kind of push method.